# Blank space generating while HTML form submit

Tags: php, http-headers, phpmailer

I have created a contact form .When we submit the form it is processed and the page is redirected using header().But the redirected page has some blank space.The blank space comes only when submitting is done.
Link:
http://deffrinjoseph.com/well/

Comment: Where is blank space?

Comment: the space just below the banner image and in the footer is widening while form submit

Comment: Post the code to help you better...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very basic CSS problem, nothing to do with php, http headers or PHPMailer.

You are setting the `headerLine` class to `height:100%`, so it's expanding to the full height of the window. To find this right click the space and select 'inspect element'. I don't understand how you can claim to be a web designer and not know this?

You really need to get rid of that ripple animation. It's pretty but it absolutely kills browser performance - I've got 8 Xeon CPUs maxed out here, so I hate to think what it would do to a mobile browser.

Comment: So look back up the DOM tree and see what's constraining it.